# .bashrc,.bash_profile and .bash_logout files in SFTP directory on CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, centos, sftp, bash

I installed OpenSSH server and set up SFTP users. When SFTP user logs in via FTP client, they see three files - .bashrc,.bash_profile and .bash_logout.

How can i hide them from users? If it matters, there are will be multiple users each one mapped to it's own directory.

Answer (score 0):

These files only make sense for shell logins so assuming you don't expect your SFTP users log onto the machine using `rsh`/`ssh`, you can get rid of these files.

One more thing, I am not SFTP expert but at least for traditional FTP it is considered insecure to let users FTP to their home directory. Unless it is required, consider using a sandbox directory.